# Не отправляется почта с спецсимволами от обычного пользователя

Tags: php, битрикс, email, vagrant

Не отправляется почта с русскими символами в теле письма и различными спецсимволами, функция `mail()` просто возвращает `false`, но отправляется отложено через cron, всё через ту же функцию. При отправке используется шаблон письма Jade, отправки напрямую идёт через bitrix. Почта отлавливается через MailCatcher.

Comment: "с русскими символами и различными спецсимволами" в адресе, в имени адресата, в теме или в теле письма?

Comment: в теле письма, поправил